# How to distinguish normal sql query and joining query using jsqlparser?

Tags: java

I was trying to get all the details of a sql query. If I provide the query "`SELECT a,b FROM TAB1 INNER JOIN TAB2 ON TAB1.a=TAB2.b WHERE a>5`", then its working fine. But when it's "`SELECT a,b FROM Tab`" then it throws exception "`java.lang.NullPointerException`".
The corresponding code is,

```
public class ParseJSQLService implements ParseJSQLServiceInterface
{
    TablesNamesFinder tablesNamesFinder = new TablesNamesFinder();

@Override
public QueryDetails parseSqlDetails(QueryDetails queryDetails) throws    JSQLParserException 
{
    CCJSqlParserManager parserManager = new CCJSqlParserManager();
    String sql=queryDetails.getQueryText();
    Statement statement=parserManager.parse(new StringReader(sql));
            String joinType="";
    if(statement instanceof Select)
    {
        Select selectstatement=(Select) statement;
        System.out.println(selectstatement);
        PlainSelect plainSelect=(PlainSelect) selectstatement.getSelectBody();
        String fromItems=plainSelect.getFromItem().toString();
        String fieldItems=plainSelect.getSelectItems().toString();


        System.out.println("fromItems====>"+fromItems);
        System.out.println("fieldItems====>"+fieldItems);

        List tableList=tablesNamesFinder.getTableList(selectstatement);
        System.out.println(tableList.size());

        System.out.println(tableList.toString());

        joinType=plainSelect.getJoins().toString();
        System.out.println("joinType====>"+joinType);
    }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that **JSQLParser** finds in your second SQL no joins. Therefore `plainSelect.getJoins()` delivers `null`. Thats why `plainSelect.getJoins().toString()` throws a NullPointerException. A slightly modification will make your code work with the second SQL as well.

```
if (plainSelect.getJoins() != null) {
    joinType = plainSelect.getJoins().toString();
    System.out.println("joinType====>" + joinType);
}
```

Comment: If it helped you, make it a useful answer ;). I don't know which version of JSqlParser you use, but may I introduce my fork at github: https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser. The development of the original at sourceforge seems to be stuck.

Comment: So if it worked and helped you please accept this answer or vote it up. You know thats the way stackexchange works.